# Как сменить состояние у делегата ListView в QML?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Допустим есть `ListView`. У делегата два состояния `folded` и `unfolded`, по умолчанию все делегаты свернуты (`folded`). При клике на делегат, я меняю его состояние на противоположное, то есть, если был свернут - разворачиваю, если развернут - сворачиваю. Теперь вопрос, как сделать так, чтоб в один момент времени мог быть развернут только один элемент списка? Мне нужно, чтобы при разворачивании одного, остальные развернутые - сворачивались. Дайте наводку на доки или `qmlbook`, где подобное описано.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто. Используем индексы модели, в делегате пишем - `state: listView.currentIndex === model.index ? "unfolded" : "collapsed"`, а при клике меняем `listView.currentIndex = model.index`. Вот и все. Надеюсь начинающим поможет.